# How to sum repetitions of a value and add it in two values of a key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

Im trying to to create a hash with one key per each type of extension on a directory. To every key I would like to add two values: number of times that extension is repeated and total size of all the files with that extension.

Something similar to this:

`{".md" => {"ext_reps" => 6, "ext_size_sum" => 2350}, ".txt" => {"ext_reps" => 3, "ext_size_sum" => 1300}}`

But I´m stuck on this step:

```
hash = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = {}}
ext_reps = 0
ext_size_sum = 0

Dir.glob("/home/computer/Desktop/**/*.*").each do |file|
  hash[File.extname(file)].store "ext_reps", ext_reps
  hash[File.extname(file)].store "ext_size_sum", ext_size_sum 
end

p hash
```

With this result:

`{".md" => {"ext_reps" => 0, "ext_size_sum" => 0}, ".txt" => {"ext_reps" => 0, "ext_size_sum" => 0}}`

And I can't finde the way to increment `ext_reps` and `ext_siz_sum`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the file name extensions and files sizes drawn are as follows.

```
files = [{ ext: 'a', size: 10 },
         { ext: 'b', size: 20 },
         { ext: 'a', size: 30 },
         { ext: 'c', size: 40 },
         { ext: 'b', size: 50 },
         { ext: 'a', size: 60 }]
```

You can use [Hash#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

```
files.group_by { |h| h[:ext] }.
      transform_values do |arr|
        { "ext_reps"=>arr.size, "ext_size_sum"=>arr.sum { |h| h[:size] } }
      end
        #=> {"a"=>{"ext_reps"=>3, "ext_size_sum"=>100},
        #    "b"=>{"ext_reps"=>2, "ext_size_sum"=>70},
        #    "c"=>{"ext_reps"=>1, "ext_size_sum"=>40}}
```

Note that the first calculation is as follows.

```
files.group_by { |h| h[:ext] }
  #=> {"a"=>[{:ext=>"a", :size=>10}, {:ext=>"a", :size=>30},
  #          {:ext=>"a", :size=>60}],
  #    "b"=>[{:ext=>"b", :size=>20}, {:ext=>"b", :size=>50}],
  #    "c"=>[{:ext=>"c", :size=>40}]}
```

---

Another way is use the forms of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`) and [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employ a block to compute the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. (Ruby does not consult that block when a key-value pair with key `k` is being merged into the hash being built (`h`) when `h` does not have a key `k`.)

See the docs for an explanation of the three parameters of the block that returns the values of common keys of hashes being merged.

```
files.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
   h.update(g[:ext]=>{"ext_reps"=>1, "ext_size_sum"=>g[:size]}) do |_k,o,n|
     o.merge(n) { |_kk, oo, nn| oo + nn }
   end
end
  #=> {"a"=>{"ext_reps"=>3, "ext_size_sum"=>100},
  #    "b"=>{"ext_reps"=>2, "ext_size_sum"=>70},
  #    "c"=>{"ext_reps"=>1, "ext_size_sum"=>40}}
```

I've chosen names for the common keys of the "outer" and "inner" hashes (`_k` and `_kk`, respectively) that begin with an underscore to signal to the reader that they are not used in the block calculation. This is common practive.

Note that this approach avoids the creation of a temporary hash similar to that created by `group_by` and therefore tends to use less memory than the first approach.

Comment: Thanks Cary, people like you make Ruby great

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution inspired by the answers given by *Cary Swoveland* and *BenFenner*

```
hash = {}

Dir.glob("/home/computer/Desktop/**/*.*").each do |file|
  (hash[File.extname(file)] ||= []) << file.size
end

hash.transform_values! { |sizes| { "ext_reps" => sizes.count, "ext_size_sum" => sizes.sum } }
```

Answer (score 2):

With `each_with_object` and nested `Hash.new`

```rb
files = [{ ext: 'a', size: 10 },
         { ext: 'b', size: 20 },
         { ext: 'a', size: 30 },
         { ext: 'c', size: 40 },
         { ext: 'b', size: 50 },
         { ext: 'a', size: 60 }]
```

```rb
files.each_with_object(Hash.new(Hash.new(0))) do |el, hash|
  h = hash[el[:ext]]

  hash[el[:ext]] =
    { "ext_reps" => h["ext_reps"] + 1, "ext_size_sum" => h["ext_size_sum"] + el[:size] }
end

#=> {"a"=>{"ext_reps"=>3, "ext_size_sum"=>100},
#    "b"=>{"ext_reps"=>2, "ext_size_sum"=>70},
#    "c"=>{"ext_reps"=>1, "ext_size_sum"=>40}}
```

Comment: `Hash.new(Hash.new(0))`: nice!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most "Ruby-like" solution, but going along with your provided example this is probably what you'd ultimately end up with as a solution. Your main problem was that you were never incrementing the `ext_reps` value, nor were you ever accumulating the `ext_size_sum` value.

```
hash = {}
Dir.glob('/home/computer/Desktop/**/*.*').each do |file|
  file_extension = File.extname(file)

  if hash[file_extension].nil?
    # This is the first time this file extension has been seen, so initialize things for it.

    hash[file_extension]                 = {}
    hash[file_extension]['ext_reps']     = 0
    hash[file_extension]['ext_size_sum'] = 0
  end

  # Increment/accumulate values.
  hash[file_extension]['ext_reps']     += 1
  hash[file_extension]['ext_size_sum'] += file.size
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a reiteration of Cary's and others' answers without temporary variables. (Which is more Ruby-like IMHO.)

```rb
Dir.glob("*.*")
   .group_by { |f| File.extname(f) }
   .transform_values do |files|
      {
        "count" => files.count,
        "size" => files.sum { |f| File.size(f) }
      }
   end
```

```
=> {".app"=>{"count"=>1, "size"=>96},          
 ".sh-builder"=>{"count"=>1, "size"=>192},
 ".sh-names"=>{"count"=>1, "size"=>288},
 ".json"=>{"count"=>2, "size"=>5362},
 ".rb"=>{"count"=>1, "size"=>132}}
```